# jQuery.get() - Practical uses?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand why you would use [`jQuery.get()` and `jQuery.get(index)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/get).  The docs say it is to convert the jQuery selection to the raw DOM object instead of working with the selection as a jQuery object and the methods available to it.

So a quick example:

```
$("div").get(0).innerHTML;
```

is the same as:

```
$("div").html();
```

Obviously this is a bad example but I am struggling to figure when you would use `.get()`.  Can you help me understand when I would use this method in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cody Lindley (jQuery Team Member) has a [great example](http://codylindley.com/Webdev/355/jquery-get-caching-dom-nodes-in-an-array) of why you would use get()

> If you ever need to cache a set of elements, because you are about to remove them, the jQuery get() method is really handy. For example, in the code below I am saving all my `<li>` elements on the page in an array, removing them, and then adding them back into the page using this array. Make sense?

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<ul> 
    <li>test</li> 
    <li>test</li> 
    <li>test</li> 
    <li>test</li> 
    <li>test</li> 
    <li>test</li> 
    <li>test</li> 
    <li>test</li> 
 </ul>

<script>

var test = $('ul li').get();

$('ul').empty();

$.each(test, function(){ $('ul').append('<li>'+$(this).html() + ' new</li>'); });

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

It happens often when you want to call a native JS method on an element.

```
//submitting a form...
$('#mySearchForm').get().submit();
```

Comment: You could also force click the submit button $("input#submit").click(); to do the same.

Comment: Hmm...I was having a brain fart this morning too.  There is also a jQuery method that will trigger a submit.  $('#mySearchForm').submit(); will also work.  I don't consider your answer a practacle use of get().

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you're using jQuery in noConflict mode and you want to do something like:

```
var element = jQuery('#jquery_selectors .are > .awesome[and=fast]').get(0);
```

And then do something in prototype:

```
$(element).whatever();
```

Comment: I think this is the best practical use case so far.  I am still hoping for a use case that isn't dependent on another library.

Comment: I think you'll find that `get` is just there for completeness sake. Eg, you can turn a DOM element into a jQuery object with el = $(document.getElementById('something')) therefore you should be able to turn a jQuery object into a DOM element with el.get().

Answer (score 3):

This may come in handy when doing something like (psuedocode):

```
a = $("div").get()
ajaxsend(a)
```

There are times when you may need to pass the actual DOM object to other functions, which may not be able to handle the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

This is useful for accessing any JavaScript method that isn't exposed through jQuery. For example, before jQuery supported offset(), I would typically use `get()` like this:

```
var offTop = $(element).get(0).offsetTop;
```

For another example, I used this recently to determine the scrollHeight of an element.

```
var scrollHeight = $(element).get(0).scrollHeight;
```

This can also be written as:

```
var scrollHeight = $(element)[0].scrollHeight;
```

Comment: This is great, is there a list of DOM properties/methods that aren't yet supported in jQuery that might be of use with the get() method?  That would be good to know.

Comment: I asked a follow question and now I am not so sure your answer is so practical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770475/dom-properties-methods-that-arent-available-in-jquery/770719#770719

Answer (score 0):

Another possible use of get() is when you are working with XML trees in jQuery.

Comment: Just something silly like:
var xml = $('<dc xmlns="#"><title>Title</title></xml>');
var title = $('title', xml).get(0);

I don't have any practical uses for it, but I can imagine more circumstances where you want the underlying DOM outside of HTML-land (say, tossing the tree into an XPath matcher or something...)

Answer (score 0):

I use it to get id for single element

```
 $(selector).get(0).id
```