# DOM properties/methods that aren't available in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Following up on my [question about jQuery.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765698/jquery-get-practical-uses) I was wondering if there is a list of DOM properties and methods that aren't available in jQuery that can only be accessible if you were working with the raw DOM object (i.e. $("#someID").get().scrollHeight; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't encountered a list but if one existed it would probably be quite lengthy. In addition to browser-specific (proprietary) properties there's a bunch of other less useful properties and methods not currently abstracted by jQuery. But then, I don't really see this as a problem, or even a valid point of discussion because jQuery IS JavaScript; if you need access to something beyond what jQuery provides then you can use **`get()`** or access a specified element within one of your "jQuery collections" like an array:

```
jQuery(elem)[0].someDOMProperty;
```

Plus jQuery provides absolutely no support for non-element nodes within the DOM. If, for whatever reason, you need direct access to comment nodes, text nodes etc. then you'll need to use the "raw" DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a compiled list of DOM operations/properties that are NOT available in jQuery (and a quick google search didn't turn anything up), but if you go to http://api.jquery.com/ you can see the entire API, and even download it as an Adobe AIR app in case you don't have internet when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Every attribute of every element is accessible through the [`attr()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) function. If you could do a `document.getElementById()` on that element and then access a property, you can also do it using the `attr()` function. However, some properties are accessed more easily in other ways when using jquery. For example, to see if an element is hidden or visible, you could do:

```
var isVisible=$("#el").is(":visible");
```

instead of using the `attr()` method. Similarly, you can find the `selectedIndex` of dropdowns and the text of the selected option, in easier ways than using the `attr()` method. [This pdf](http://comp345.awardspace.com/select_element_cheatsheet.pdf) outlines some of these easier approaches.

To access a css property, you are better off doing:

```
var fontWeight=$("#el").css("fontWeight");
```

rather than using `get()` or `attr()`. You can also set the css properties in this way, e.g:

```
$("#el").css("fontWeight","bold");
```

Comment: DOM properties are *not* the same as HTML attributes, and definitely don't have anything to do with CSS.

Comment: Where have I claimed that they are?

Comment: The OP is about DOM properties, not HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

No. JQuery is just JavaScript. If you can do it in JavaScript, you can do it in jQuery. Some properties and methods are overwritten in the context of a jQuery object and that's where you would want to us the get() method--to 'get' (i.e. access) the standard property/method.

That's really as complicated as it is.

Comment: $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){});

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong, but I think you can access any properties via the attr method.

Comment: the $.attr() method only accesses the attributes of a single element in the DOM. I think he means the DOM in general, not just a specific tag.

Comment: Huh?  I know it accesses for a single element. Attributes are specific to elements when you are accessing them.  I don't understand what you are trying to say here..

Comment: attr gets the HTML properties, like the "href" in <a href="..."> -- DOM properties are things like childNodes, nodeType, innerHTML, parentNode.

Comment: @nick, you can retrieve all of these properties using the attr() method. If it works on one dom attrib such as innerHTML, it will work with all.

Comment: Please try something before you comment that someone else is wrong.

Comment: attr() only works on DOM properties (eg attr('childNodes')) by accident. http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr clearly outlines that attr()s intent is to get/set html attributes, not arbitrary properties. If it wasn't, attr('childNodes', someValue) would work.